# How can I check if an element attribute returns "display: none" in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using selenium, I would like to check on a certain website if the username "Natalie" is available. If it's not, the website brings up a pop-up saying the name is not available, but I don't know how to check for the popup specifically since it's in the innerHTML. I decided to get and check the attributes of the pop-up since it returns "display: none" when a username is available, but it still isn't working.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="username"]""")
element.send_keys("Natalie")
elementcheck = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="username-exists"]""")
style = elementcheck.get_attribute('style')
if 'none' in style:
    print("Natalie is taken.")
else:
    print("Natalie is not taken.")
```

The HTML element is (when a username is available):

```
<p id="username-exists" class="error-username feedback error" style="display: none;">Username is already taken.</p>
```

The HTML element is (when a username is not available):

```
<p id="username-exists" class="error-username feedback error" style="">Username is already taken.</p>
```

Comment: You should try using the method value_of_css_property('display')

Comment: Can you share the HTML when User is not present?

Comment: @DebanjanB
Do you mean when nothing's typed in the box? It's the same as when a username is available. I updated it with what it shows when a username is not available.

Comment: @ally I agree with your second HTML. But your first HTML is not correct I guess. When User is not present I think the `<p>` tag is not visible at all. Agree?

Comment: @DebanjanB It's always visible when inspecting it. The only difference is that when there's a username available, there is also "style="display: none;"" in order to hide the "Username is already taken" popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an element's attribute contains style="display: none;" which means element is **`Hidden`** then **`Selenium`** won't be able to interact with the element. So as per your Question, if you want to check if you want to check the availavility of a `Display Name` you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://playdauntless.com/accounts/")
display_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='username']")
display_name.send_keys("Natalie")
display_name.submit()
try :
    my_style = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//p[@id='username-exists']")))
    print("Natalie is taken.")
except :
    print("Natalie is not taken.")
```

Console Output :

```
Natalie     => Natalie is taken.
Debanjan    => Debanjan is not taken.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **is_displayed()** method for your element:

```
if elementcheck.is_displayed():
    print("Natalie is taken.")
else:
    print("Natalie is not taken.")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The program just skips to else:, even though the name is taken.

Comment: the webpage check the name avability when u type or after a button click or maybe a tab key press?

Comment: After typing the name in, no button clicks or keystrokes required.